# How to normalize samples of an ongoing cumulative sum?

Tags: audio, integral, normalize, discrete

For simplicity let's assume we have a function **sin(x)** and calculated 1000 samples between -1 and 1 with it. We can plot those samples. Now in the next step we want to plot the integral of sin(x) which would be **- cos(x) + C**. Now i can calculate the integral with my existing samples like this:

**y[n] = x[n] + y[n-1]**

Because it's a cumulative sum we will need to normalize it to get samples between -1 and 1 on the y axis.

**y = 2 * ( x - min(x) / max(x) - min(x) ) - 1**

To normalize we need a maximum and a minimum.

Now we want to calculate the next 1000 samples for sin(x) and calculate the integral again. Because it's a cumulative sum we will have a **new maximum** which means we will need to normalize all of our 2000 samples.

**Now my question basically is:**

How can i normalize samples in this context without knowing the maximum and minimum?
How can i prevent, to normalize all previous samples again, if i have a new set of samples with a new maximum/minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution :)

I also want to mention: This is about periodic functions like Sine, so basically the maximum and minimum should be always the same, right?

**In a special case this isn't true:**

If you samples don't contain a full period of the function (with global maximum and minimum of the function). This can happen when you choose a very low frequency.

**What can you do:**

- Simply calculate the samples for a function like sin(x) with a
  frequency of 1. It will contain the global maximum and minimum of the function *(it's important that y varies between -1 and 1, not 0 and 1!)*.
- Then you calculate the integral with the cumulative sum.
- get maximum and minimum of the samples
- you can scale it up or down: **maximum/frequency**, **minimum/frequency**
- can be used now to normalize samples which were calculated with any other frequency.

It only need to be calculated once at the beginning.